# Custom types as properties in QT Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

I am developing a custom widget to QT Designer.

Everything works fine for basic QT types and list, but I have a problem when defining a property of a custom type.

Here is the declaration of the property :

```
    Q_PROPERTY(Courbe* courbes READ getcourbe WRITE setcourbe1 DESIGNABLE true)

public:
    TestCourbe(QWidget *parent = 0);

    Courbe* TestCourbe::getcourbe() const ;
    void TestCourbe::setcourbe1(Courbe *n);
```

Here is the beginning of the definition of my Courbe class :

```
class Courbe : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString valeursX READ readvaleurX WRITE setvaleurX)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString valeursY READ readvaleurY WRITE setvaleurY)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString legende READ readlegende WRITE setlegende)
```

The problem is the Courbe property is not displayed in QT Designer.
Should I add something to the Courbe declaration ? (I've seen the 
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE macro but this is for QML only right ?)

thanks

Comment: `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE` is not only for QML. Every time you use a custom type for properties you need to register it. [Read this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/properties.html#properties-and-custom-types) for more info about that

Comment: thx @thuga ...I've read that but I was kind of confused by one example I found...anyway, it does not change anything

Comment: Have you read [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4029)?

Comment: @thuga. Nope, I didn't. I guess the answer is you can't do what I want...If you write an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it is not possible to show custom type properties in the designer.

The reason for this is explained in [this thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/4029). Basically the designer doesn't know what editor to use for custom type properties.